# htaccess file being ignored, trying to leverage browser caching for Pagespeed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite, pagespeed

I'm having a problem with my .htaccess file. I'm optimizing my site using Google Pagespeed and GTMetrix and both keep saying "leverage browser caching". So I just added my .htaccess file and included the following lines

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
    </IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
      </filesMatch>
    </ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

I first had nothing, then I tried with just the 'expires caching', first piece of code and after that didn't change a thing in the re-tested results, I added the second pair of code -> cache control headers. Strangely, I'm still scoring the same.

I'm on the verge of thinking my HTaccess file looks alright, but there is a problem on perhaps my server.. Or well, I just don't know. You guys probably do!

My .htaccess file is in the same folder as the index.html and assets folders are located.
The file structure looks like this:

> /public_html/domain/company_name/website/.htaccess - For the .htaccess file
>   /public_html/domain/company_name/website/index.html - For the index.html file

[THIS URL](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website) will link to the index.html file above.

When writing the title, I saw numbers of other related topics, however, most of them didn't work.
Where many related topics posted something about a corrupted or interfering file in the /etc/.. I don't have a /etc/ folder, so that couldn't be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem! For anyone who can't find why it ain't working for them, try this!

My problem was that mod_expires wasn't active.

Create a php file and paste in the following code

```
<?php
  print_r(apache_get_modules());
?>
```

And see if mod_expires is active. If it isn't showing, try [this tutorial](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/08/02/howto-enable-or-disable-modules-in-apache/) to active mod_expires. Then edit your htaccess file again and you'll probably see it's working!

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()"

Comment: It's a bit difficult for me to actually help you, since I did a lot by googling. However, you can google this function above -> (print_r(apache_get_modules()); <- and see how to use it. What's easiest is to simply create a file (i.e. "apache-modules.php") and write the above piece of code inside. Upload the file to your server and navigate to it (i.e. domain.com/apache-modules.php). It should show you a list of all apache modules enabled. If, like in my case, it wasn't enabled you should google how to enable it. If it was enabled, there is something different going on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think it not working has to do with the environment. The method simply is not available..

Comment: Hi, It return: Array ( [0] => mod_rewrite [1] => mod_mime [2] => mod_headers [3] => mod_expires [4] => mod_auth_basic ). So, mod_expires is active. Right?